# Does securing one’s items to another’s property confer any duty upon the owner of the land?

Tags: england-and-wales, private-property

Alice is walking along the street with a pram when suddenly a thief takes her bag and she must quickly run after him so she chains her pram to a nearby fence in order to pursue the thief.

This fence is on private property, and actually separates Bob’s and Charles’s lands. Bob shortly returns home, sees the pram, and cuts the chain before dumping the pram which was on his land into the skip.

Did Bob have a duty to make efforts to identify and contact the pram’s owner, such as by at least retaining the pram in secure storage, in case its owner should return in search of it, even if he would be entitled to charge her for the time it was stored for?

Does the position change if Bob’s property was rather the premises of a business with implied permission for public access, such as a Tesco?